# Azure Windows Eventlog Level

Tags: c#, xml, events, azure, diagnostics

I can't find something helpful anywhere... How do the raw Windows Azure: Windows Event Log-XML looks like. I need to know which EventLevel refers to an number.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about an XML file I'm assuming you are referring to the **diagnostics.wadcfg** file. In this file, you simply write the LogLevel as defined in the XSD:

```
  <xs:simpleType name="LogLevel">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="Undefined" />
      <xs:enumeration value="Verbose" />
      <xs:enumeration value="Information" />
      <xs:enumeration value="Warning" />
      <xs:enumeration value="Error" />
      <xs:enumeration value="Critical" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
```

If you need the numeric values of each level (I think this is also something you're asking), you can find them through the enum:

```
namespace Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics
{
    // Summary:
    //     Defines a standard set of logging levels.
    public enum LogLevel
    {
        // Summary:
        //     Logs all events at all levels.
        Undefined = 0,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Logs a critical alert.
        Critical = 1,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Logs an error.
        Error = 2,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Logs a warning.
        Warning = 3,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Logs an informational message.
        Information = 4,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Logs a verbose message.
        Verbose = 5,
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot. Thats what i searched :)